# Private Data Collection: GET_STATE failed --> Policy Issue?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to use private data collection in my Network. Therefore i added

> err = stub.PutPrivateData("privateData",key, DATA)

to my ChainCode create Assets Functions.

Beforehand I created a collection with 2 Organizations being able to access this private data and have it in their SideDBs for that:

```
[{
   "name": "privateData",
   "policy": "OR('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')",
   "requiredPeerCount": 0,
   "maxPeerCount": 3,
   "blockToLive":0,
   "memberOnlyRead": true
 }]
```

When i now create an asset + private Data with Org1 everything went successful. I could create the data and also am able to read the on chain data (with normal query GetState) **and the private Data succesfully**

> valAsBytes, err := stub.GetPrivateData("privateData", key)

When i now identify as the peer of Org2MSP and make a read query on the private Data with the exact same query from above it tells me this error:

```
GET_STATE failed: transaction ID: fc4de5a8a987765ab0ab4b6bc4f767249b4f74aefdad7e0036782faa4d95494e: private data matching public hash version is not available. Public hash version = &version.Height{BlockNum:0x2, TxNum:0x0}, Private data version = (*version.Height)
```

Hyperledger Fabric Tutorial tells me when this error appears the calling Organization has not access to this data. But i added this organization to the relevant policy in the collection.

Do you have an idea what goes wrong here? What should i change? I tried swapping policies/adjusting configtx etc. but nothing worked out.

Comment: Ok nvm i did it now. Everything is done right in the above. I just forgot to to run channel updates. Now everything works fine.

Comment: How can i run channel updates ?